# Using ColdFusion to parse WSDL/SOAP

Tags: web-services, soap, coldfusion, lucee

I'm passing in a USERID into what I believe to be either a SOAP request. I've never worked with SOAP and not quite sure where to start so if my question doesn't quite make sense, let me know and I'll try to fill in missing details.

Context for question:
I'm converting an excel macro (the macro will query pass the userid to the server and the server will return employee details such as name, email, address, etc.) and turning into a web lookup.

I have the following code:

```
<cfscript>
variables.sso = '55555';
variables.serverURL = "http://search.corporate.ge.com/ldq/Query";
variables.queryString = "?serverID=ssoprod&searchBase=ou=domainWorker,+o=domain.com&Prebuilt=true&scope=2&filter=(domainoraclehrid=#variables.sso#)";
variables.webservice = "#variables.serverURL##variables.queryString#";
</cfscript>

<cfdump var="#variables.webservice#">
<cfhttp url="#variables.webservice#" method="get" result="response"></cfhttp>
<cfdump var="#response.fileContent#" label="soap content">
```

When I take the value from the dump of variables.webservice, and paste it directly into a browser, I get the following (assume userID of 55555):

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.  
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:dsml="http://www.dsml.org/DSML">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <dsml:dsml xmlns:dsml="http://www.dsml.org/DSML">
        <dsml:directory-entries>
            <dsml:entry dn="domainssouid=1D8B0D04-91F0-1CAE-9BD7-002128B20D70,ou=domainWorker, o=domain.com">
            ...
            <dsml:attr name="employeetype">
                <dsml:value>Contractor</dsml:value>
            </dsml:attr>
            <dsml:attr name="givenname">
                <dsml:value>John</dsml:value>
            </dsml:attr>
            <dsml:attr name="postalcode">
                <dsml:value>90210</dsml:value>
            </dsml:attr>
            <dsml:attr name="domainoraclehrid">
                <dsml:value>456456987</dsml:value>
            </dsml:attr>
            <dsml:attr name="mail">
                <dsml:value>John.Doe@domain.com</dsml:value>
            </dsml:attr>
            <dsml:attr name="cn">
                <dsml:value>Doe, John</dsml:value>
            </dsml:attr>
            ...
        </dsml:entry>
    </dsml:directory-entries>
</dsml:dsml>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

BUT when I dump of #response.fileContent#, I get something different, I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:f="http://www.w3.org/2001/06/soap-faults">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
            <SOAP-ENV:faultcode>MustUnderstand</SOAP-ENV:faultcode>
            <SOAP-ENV:faultstring>ou=domainWorker,+o=domain.com: [LDAP: error code 34 - Invalid DN], Name Not valid - ou=domainWorker,+o=domain.com - filter -(domainoraclehrid=55555) </SOAP-ENV:faultstring>
        </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Ultimately what I'd like to do is parse out the "cn", and "mail" details. What am I missing here? I suspect it might have something to do with ME accessing the URL directly (logged in user) where as the request is being made from a server and isn't "authenticated". If that is the case, how can I resolve this?

Comment: As you say, it could be authentication. Does it work if you try it in a private window?  It could also be a problem with url parameter encoding, or different headers being sent by the browser.  Use your browser's web console to see what it is sending for the successful request. Also, for grins, try replacing that + with a space.

Comment: When I replaced the + with a [space], the space was URL encoded to %20 and the same results were returned (the good results).

Comment: Sorry, for the last part, I meant change the `+` to a space in the cfhttp call.  The rest of it is things to investigate in your browser (using a private tab, reviewing the web console headers, url params, etc..). i.e. Figure out what's different about the browser call and why it succeeds.

Comment: If you will put your comment in there about grinning, I mean removing the +, I can mark it as the answer. :) I was able to parse the XML tree and get the data I needed.

Comment: Is there a better way to get the values I need than this? `<cfset email = "#doc.XmlRoot.XmlChildren[1].XmlChildren[1].XmlChildren[1].XmlChildren[1].XmlChildren[11].XmlChildren[1].XmlText#">`?

Comment: I assume you mean the attribute named "mail"? If the response only has one attribute with that name, a relative search should work `xmlSearch(doc, "//dsml:attr[@name='mail']")`. If not, better to open a new thread so xml question is easier for the next guy to find.

Comment: Just curious, what's your CF version, `#server.coldfusion#`? I was confused at first because in CF2018, it's encoded as `%20`. Maybe your version is handling it differently?

Comment: It's actually Lucee 5.2.9.31 (Version Name: Velvet). What are you referring to as "it", the plus [+] or the space [ ]?

Comment: Gah, I accidentally edited out all the context.  Yes, I meant to say `+` was encoded as `%20`. I didn't realize you were using Lucee, but that explains it!  I couldn't figure out why I was getting different results ;-) CF2018 encoded it as `%20` (space) while Lucee encodes it as `%2B` (plus sign).  That explains why the target server is complaining about the parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

(Originally, I was a little perplexed about why I couldn't reproduce your results with CF2018, but now that I know you're using Lucee, the difference makes sense.)

Looking over the successful response, I noticed it doesn't contain a `+`, before the ["o" (organization Name)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4519#section-2.19):

```
<dsml:entry dn="domainssouid=xxxx,ou=domainWorker, o=domain.com">
```

Which means the VBA call is treating the `+` as an encoding for a space, but CFHTTP is encoding it as a literal plus sign instead, causing an error because it breaks the LDAP query:

> [LDAP: error code 34 - Invalid DN], Name Not valid - ou=domainWorker,**+o**=domain.com

The solution is to get rid of the plus sign `+` and replace it with a space:

```
searchBase=ou=domainWorker, o=domain.com
```

Interestingly, dumping the http request data shows that apparently CF2018 does things differently. Unlike Lucee, CF2018 treats the plus sign as a space.

**CF2018 => `%20` (space)**

```
searchBase=ou%3DdomainWorker%2C%20o%3Ddomain.com
```

**Lucee 5.2.8.50 => `%2B` (plus sign)**

```
searchBase=ou%3DdomainWorker%2C%2Bo%3Ddomain.com
```